# How do I get Eclipse to respect the @FixMethodOrder JUnit directive?

Tags: eclipse, maven, junit

I’m using Eclipse Kepler (Java 8). with my Maven (v 3.2.3) project.  I’m using JUnit 4.11, as declared in my pom.xml file …

```
            <dependency>
                    <groupId>junit</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                    <version>4.11</version>
                    <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
```

I’m trying to run some JUnit tests and I have this at the top of my tests

```
@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)
public class MyTest
{
```

However, when I run the test in Eclipse (by right clicking the name of the file and selecting “Run As”, “JUnit Test”), Eclipse is not running the tests in ascending order by name, but instead running the tests one by one as they are listed in the file.

My question is, how can I get Eclipse to respect the “FixMethodOrder” directive in my file?  Note that I’m not interested in lectures about why it shouldn’t matter what order you run JUnit tests in.

Answer (score 0):

Open your project build path (right-click on project > Build Path > Configure Build Path...) and go to the Libraries tab.  Do you have "JUnit 4" on your Eclipse classpath or just "Maven Dependencies":

[image: Sample Build Path Libraries tab]

Remove it by selecting "JUnit 4" and hitting the remove button to the right.  Maven specifies all your dependencies so you don't need Eclipse adding to that.

In my experience Eclipse seems to prefer its own JUnit library at runtime over the JUnit library provided by "Maven Dependencies": I get different results in test execution order between Eclipse and direct Maven when using `@FixMethodOrder` if the Eclipse "JUnit 4" library is on the classpath, but if I remove that library then Eclipse and Maven are in agreement.

Comment: Hi, I have a ton of dependencies that reflect what is in my pom (e.g. M2_REPO/antlr/antlr/2.7.7/antlr-2.7.7.jar - /Users/davea/.m2/repository/antlr/antlr/2.7.7/antlr-2.7.7.jar" and at the bottom there is "JRE System Library (JavaSE-1.6)", but no "JUnit 4".

Comment: So much for that theory (that Eclipse and Maven were using different JUnit jars).  Are your dependencies all grouped under the "Maven Dependencies" header or are they each added to your Eclipse classpath as a reference to a jar on disk?

Comment: They appear as references to a JAR on disk (e.g. using that "M2_REPO/..." syntax).  I'm using the M2E Eclipse plugin but am open to switching from that if that is somehow the root of the problem.